# need a client request dataset

Tags: data-request, database

I'm looking for a dataset for client requests (requests posted in forums) for buying device requests (like "I Want a good budget phone with 2GB ram And Snapdragon Processer.").

Comment: Only the requests? Only questions, or any form of breakdown into components of the question? In what format? Your question really needs a lot of improvement, please [read this](http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like) and [edit] your text (don't forget to make your title specific).